# :first-child not working unless the parent is <div>

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

Can someone explain the theory behind this?
I have this code;
https://jsfiddle.net/vikaskulkarni/cnLdwxza/1/

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Articles</title>
    <style>
      .bodyCls {
        float: left;
      }

      .bodyCls article {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
      }

      article:first-child {
        background-color: red;
      }

      article:nth-child(2) {
        background-color: yellow;
      }

      article:nth-child(3) {
        background-color: blue;
      }

      article:last-child {
        background-color: green;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="bodyCls">
    <div>
      <article>First</article>
      <article>Second</article>
      <article>Third</article>
      <article>Fourth</article>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

And this works fine.
However, if I remove the DIV from body as in this link, the first-child selector does not work,
https://jsfiddle.net/vikaskulkarni/95gbpmf8/1/

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Articles</title>
    <style>
      .bodyCls {
        float: left;
      }

      .bodyCls article {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
      }

      article:first-child {
        background-color: red;
      }

      article:nth-child(2) {
        background-color: yellow;
      }

      article:nth-child(3) {
        background-color: blue;
      }

      article:last-child {
        background-color: green;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="bodyCls">
      <article>First</article>
      <article>Second</article>
      <article>Third</article>
      <article>Fourth</article>
  </body>

</html>
```

I searched across the net and saw that there is always a DIV involved while using the selector. So I am bit confused about the way these selectors work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect your DOM, it turns out that there are an additional 3 elements being added inside the `<body>` tag, by the browser. the `:first-child` operator will only work IF the element being targeted is an `<article>` AND the first child of its parent. This is not the case, since the `<first-child>` is actually the `<meta>` tag. This is why your logic is failing when you remove the div.

[image: Description]

To make it work without the `<div>`, you could update your CSS styles to something like this:

```
  article:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: red;
  }

  article:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  article:nth-child(6) {
    background-color: blue;
  }

  article:nth-child(7) {
    background-color: green;
  }
```

I would personally recommend to use a wrapping `<div>`, since it keeps both your HTML and the corresponding CSS organized. Also, the ordering of the extra tags added by the browser may vary across different browsers, so the above setup is not guaranteed to work across every browser. Using a `<div>` will guarantee it, since your `<article>` tags will always be the only children of the wrapping div.

Comment: Thanks, so, the question is how to make this work without the DIV?

Comment: Aamir, by looking at his code you can clearly see his `meta` and `style` tag are both in the `<head>`, not in the `<body>`.

Comment: @coderHASH64codingHASH46code Check the updated answer.

Comment: @SirExotic yes, but when rendered by the DOM, they are added inside the `body` tag. Check the screenshot. At least on Chrome. As I mentioned, this might vary from browser to browser. So it's best to have a wrapping div.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

The articles are the child elements of the parent div. The `:first-child` selector requires that the element is the first child inside its parent. In this case it is not. If you remove the parent, the children are no longer children of that div, they are children of the body, and the `:first-child` selector can not be used. Note this works the same for `:last-child`

Comment: They are still the children of the body?

Comment: Yes, they are still the children of body, so I was assuming it would work

Comment: I thought that too, but if you remove the parent, the other articles still keep their background color, only the last-child is affected. That was his question.

Comment: Yes, first-child and last-child do not function the same way as nth-child

Comment: @AamirKhan yes exactly, and as you’ve discovered in your answer, the element is no longer the first child in the body. My answer does not deserve your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

every Node inside `<body></body>` is a child of body, so in your css you don't have to prefix the child class selectors with the a body class

see my Demo to understand the idea

https://jsfiddle.net/95gbpmf8/3/

```
article {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
  article:first-child {
    background-color: red;
  }

  article:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  article:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: blue;
  }

  article:last-child {
    background-color: green;
  }
```

floating a Node makes its display to "inline-block", so your article Node is now as a div with inline-block display.